# Nested Queries - select first item of table and compare it with content of other table

Tags: sql, nested, teradata

I am working with Teradata and try to use nested queries.

My query looks somehow like this:

```
create table test as
    select id, selected_value, *
    from database.table as data
    left join (select id, value, value_search 
               from database2.table2 
               where value = 1) as data2 on data.id = data2.id 
    where selected_value >= first_value_search_of_data2   /*i want to select everything that is greater or equal to the first item of data2 in column value_search*/
;
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: What is the *first item of a table*, your Where-condition implies `value = 1`? Do you want to compare to the *first item* for each ID. Can you show some example data and expec ted result?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer depends on what you define by first value. ;) - But let's try:

```
SELECT ID, SELECTED_VALUE
  FROM DATABASE.TABLE AS DATA2
       LEFT JOIN (
         SELECT ID, VALUE, VALUE_SEARCH
           FROM DATABASE2.TABLE2
          WHERE VALUE = 1
          QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ID, VALUE ORDER BY VALUE_SEARCH DESC) = 1
       ) AS DATA2
       ON DATA.ID = DATA2.ID
 WHERE SELECTED_VALUE >= VALUE_SEARCH;
```

You can define your definition of first value in the ROW_NUMBER definition.

One last thing: If you don't define a PrimaryIndex (DistrubutionKey), Teradata always takes the first row. This could get an unwanted PI and therefore a highly skewed table. So I recommend to always add the primary Key definition, even when to say "NO PRIMARY INDEX"...

PS: I see the need for the SubQuery due to the expected execution plan. It doesn't make sense first to join two big tables and filter after that. It's more convenient for the Spool and the RDBMS if you join a table with a (pre-filtered) smaller sub-table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need a sub-query for your join, I have a direct join and a sub-query to find the "first" row. I am quite unsure what defines the "first" row so here I used `MAX()` since you had `>=` in your example code

```
select id, selected_value, *
from database.table as data 
left join database2.table2 as data2 on data.id = data2.id and data2.value = 1
where selected_value >= (SELECT MAX(value_search) FROM database2.table2)
```

Alternatively the last sub-query might be based on an ORDER BY instead to find the "first" row.